# read filenames and write directly into a list

Tags: python, filenames

Is it possible to get Python to look in a folder and put all of the filenames (with a certain extension) into a list?

e.g.:

```
[filename1.txt, filename2.txt,...]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this easily with the `glob` module:

```
import glob
filenames = glob.glob('<some_path>/*.<extension>')
```

Comment: good, use `os.path.basename(x) for x in glob(...)` if you don't want the full paths.

Comment: @DSM wim beat me to the edit. I should have put a "/" of course.

Comment: Ah, okay.  I thought maybe you were trying to escape the asterisk for a second (which I've sometimes done myself, accidentally.)

Answer (score 7):

I always use os module for this and works perfectly for me.

```
import os
file_list = os.listdir(path)
print(file_list)

>>> ["file1.txt", "file2.txt", etc...]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick answer I found.

```
import os

txt_files = filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.txt'), os.listdir('mydir'))
```

Comment: If you are going to do it that way you might as well use `os.path.splitext()` instead of `endswith`